# Should a java class' final fields always be static?

Tags: java, static, final

I could not find any references online about this. But just wanted to know if final fields in a class should always be `static` or is it just a convention. Based on my understanding of their uses, I feel that it is more of a logical thing to do than something that is imposed by the language.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Of course not. They must be static if they belong to the class, and not be static if they belong to the instance of the class:

```
public class ImmutablePerson {
    private static final int MAX_LAST_NAME_LENGTH = 255; // belongs to the type
    private final String firstName; // belongs to the instance
    private final String lastName; // belongs to the instance

    public ImmutablePerson(String firstName, String lastName) {
        if (lastName.length() > MAX_LAST_NAME_LENGTH) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("last name too large");
        }
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    // getters omitted for brevity
}
```

Answer (score 27):

No, absolutely not - and it's *not* a convention.

`static` and `final` are *entirely* different things. `static` means that the field relates to the *type* rather than any particular instance of the type. `final` means that the field can't change value after initial assignment (which must occur during type/instance initialization).

`static final` fields are usually for constants - whereas *instance* fields which are `final` are usually used when creating immutable types.

Answer (score 7):

They don't always come together and it's not a convention. `final` fields are often used to create immutable types:

```
class Person {

    private final String name;
    private final int age;

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

}
```

On the other hand `static` but not `final` fields are not that common and are quite tricky. `static final` is seen often because it means application<sup>1</sup>-wide constant.

<sup>1 - well, class loader-wide, to be precise</sup>

Answer (score 7):

Final fields do not *need* to be static, and sometimes it can be useful to have a non-static final instance variable. Fields that are marked both static and final are usually used for constants, like this:

```
public static final int BORDER_WIDTH = 5;
```

However, sometimes you'll see a non-static final field when an object has a immutable property. Usually, non-static `final` fields are still marked `private` for the usual reasons, though, so it's more of an extra check so the compiler can make sure you're never setting the property again.

Comment: It's not only an extra check. Final fields bring additional thread-safety guarantees.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to access them like `ClassName.FIELD`, then yes, you have to do that. If you don't make it static, you have to do something like `new ClassName().FIELD`, which is unnecessary and a pointless creation of an object.

However, if you are only using it in the class or making it `private`, then don't make it static. If you are within the actual class, you can just do `FIELD`.

To fully grasp this concept, you have to know what `static` means. Static means that it belongs to the actual class, not an instance of it.

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely not. Consider:

```
class Point {
    public final int x;
    public final int y;

    public Point(int _x, int _y) {
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
    }
}
```

Drop the `final`, and the class becomes mutable. Add a `static`, and all your points are the same, and there is no legal way to write the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely not. Immutable objects, for example, have `final` properties, that can be set only once, by the constructor.

For more information, please see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/imstrat.html

Immutable objects are not the only case in which `final` properties are used, but they provide a evident example of their usefulness.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.

**static**

- > "Indicates that only one such data field is available for all
  >   instances of this class. Without this modifier, each instance has its
  >   own copy of a data field"

  ...meaning there can only be one of this

**final**

- > "The value provided for the data field cannot be modified"

  ...meaning that this is a constant

Comment: Actually, final fields are not necessarily constant. `final` just means that the reference can not be modified, Consider for example `final Map<K,V> x = new HashMap<>();`. The map `x` is final and yet it's contents can be modified at runtime - so not [constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_(computer_programming)).